# How to get 0 rows updated query/data from Oracle in PHP?

Tags: mysql, oracle, rows, zero

Suppose I am firing query that will upadte data if all value are available else will run with 0 rows updated. So **How to get those 0 rows updated query/data from Oracle db in PHP**?

In my script, I am updating table if item_flag is N, item_name is stored in $sku so checking with that & site_code is in $final_code so all these in where condition.
so if update query runs successfully with value updation then I am taking execution result in $result & updating status of Mysql table.

But what happened is when there is some data not present say $sku in update query then query runs with **0 rows updated**...& likewise it will move to if($result) loop & update the status which I don't want as practically data/row is not get updated...

so How to get 0 rows updated query/data from Oracle in PHP?

```
        --------------some code above--------

            $query_ora_update = "UPDATE ITEM_DETAILS SET ITEM_FLAG= 'Y', LAST_UPDATE_DATE = sysdate WHERE ITEM_NAME = '$sku' AND SITE_CODE = '$final_code' AND ITEM_FLAG = 'N' ";
            $parse_result = oci_parse($conn,$query_ora_update);
            $result = oci_execute($parse_result);                          
            oci_commit($conn);

            if($result)                             
            {

               $query_update_alert = "UPDATE product_creation SET alert_status =1 where 
                    entity_id = $entity_id and sku = '$sku' and alert_status = 0";

$result_query_update_alert = mysql_query($query_update_alert);

             } 
        -------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `oci_num_rows` function. [Documentation Here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-num-rows.php)

**EDIT: Example Code**

```
$parse_result = oci_parse($conn,$query_ora_update);             
$result = oci_execute($parse_result);   
$row_count = oci_num_rows($parse_result);                                    
oci_commit($conn);              
if($row_count > 0)
  { 
   -------------------
```